# Background Worker events

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, event-handling, backgroundworker

pseudo code:

```
form1
{
    int i;
    label1;

    Add()
    {
     i++;
     label1 = i.ToString(); //#ErrorLine
    }

    backgroundworker worker;

    worker_DoWork()
    { 
     FileGuard guard = new FileGuard();
     guard.FileKilled += guard.KillH(Add);
     guard.StarGuarding(); //there is system watcher inside 
                           //this guard and some processing code
                           //that will fire event FileKilled();

    } 
}
```

Afer calling StartGuarding() worker will be compleated
But when there is event FileKilled fired I goth this error on line #ErrorLine

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the events themselves, but rather the fact that you are accessing UI controls from another thread. In Windows Forms, you are not allowed to interact with the UI from any other thread than the main UI thread.

You can use `InvokeRequired` to check whether you are on a thread that has no access to the UI, and then use `Invoke` to run code on the UI thread if required. It might look something like this:

```
private void DoStuffWithGUI() 
{
    if (InvokeRequired) 
    {
        Action work = DoStuffWithGUI;
        Invoke(work);
    }
    else
    {
        // Your normal logic
    }
}
```

You can use the UI directly from ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompletedEvents (because they are automatically marshalled to the UI thread). But all work you do within DoWork, (and therefore all events you might raise as part of the work) runs in a separate thread, and must be marshalled to the UI thread using Invoke. From MSDN for [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx):

> You must be careful not to manipulate
>   any user-interface objects in your
>   DoWork event handler. Instead,
>   communicate to the user interface
>   through the ProgressChanged and
>   RunWorkerCompleted events.

Comment: Isn't BackgroundWorker allowed to change the UI? I thought so.

Comment: No, BackgroundWorker runs on a different thread than the main UI, it is the main purpose of `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Ok. I was under the impression that it had some magic synchronization to be able to handle the GUI updates. But I just found this text in MSDN: `You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events` source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's because a third thread is used when FileKilled is invoked by the system.

As for `BackgroundWorker` you should use events to handle GUI updates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access Windows Forms or WPF objects from anything other than the form they were created on, hence your issue.

Use a dispatcher to send the update back to your UI Thread.

If you can give detail on whether you're using WinForms or WPF we can give more information.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change modify the controls from a thread other than on which they were created. You need to use the [InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) property and [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method to marshal the calls to the UI thread from the background thread.

```
private readonly _lockObject = new Object();

Add()
{
     lock(_lockObject)
     {
         i++;
         if(label1.InvokeRequired)
             Invoke(new Action( () => label1 = i.ToString()));
         else
             label1 = i.ToString();
     }
}
```

Note that the `lock` is not necessary to avoid this exception. It added to make the method thread safe.